# iOS 7: How to recalculate directions with Map Kit

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location

Is there a way to have a Map Kit map recalculate directions if the user's current location diverges from the route steps? I don't see anything in the MKDirections documentation or Map Kit functions reference that's ready-made for that.

If I have to roll my own, I'm not sure where to start. Perhaps by seeing if the user's current location diverges by a certain amount from the polyline of the current route step, although based on my scant knowledge, I wonder if some Core Location conversions would have to take place.

Comment: hi @Gregir did you came up with a solution?

Comment: I never did find a Map Kit native way of doing it, so I wrote a "checkRouteRecalculate" method that checked the distance between my current location (as a point on a polyline) against the most current MKRouteStep, and if it was outside a certain threshold that I set as a constant, I determined I was off route and recalculated. I called this custom method to make that determination every time locationManager didUpdateLocations ran. It's been a long time, but I did a lot of field testing and I remember it seemed to work pretty reliably.